# How to parse multiple xml files inside a zip file containing multiple subdirectories

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, zip

I have to search and print the results from multiple XML files stored in a zip file.
My code works pretty well in that case. But when the zip file contains multiple subdirctories and inside that XML files it shows

> File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1348, in XML
> return parser.close()
> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0

Here is my code (it works well if all the XML files are stored inside zip file without any folders)

```py
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from zipfile import ZipFile

from utils.xml import SRXMLElements

DEFAULT_ZIP = "./resources/another.zip"


def parse_xml(search_pattern) -> None:
    with ZipFile(DEFAULT_ZIP, "r") as my_zip:
        for file_name in my_zip.namelist():
            with my_zip.open(file_name) as my_file:
                root = ET.fromstring(my_file.read().decode())
                for billSummary in root.iter(SRXMLElements.BillSummaries.value):
                    for text in billSummary.iter(SRXMLElements.Text.value):
                        summary_text = text.text
                        for match in search_pattern.finditer(summary_text):
                            print(text.text)
                            for child in billSummary.iter('RECEIVEDDATE'):
                                print(child.text)
                            


def main() -> None:
   
    
    search_pattern = re.compile("1941012339")
    parse_xml(search_pattern)
  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```py
from enum import Enum


class SRXMLElements(Enum):
    BillSummaries = "Product"
    Text = "SERVICETAGNUM"
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `namelist` does not only return files. It also includes the directories. Thus, you have to check, whether `file_name` is actually a XML file or a directory.

This is the content of my test ZIP file:

```
Archive:  another.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       30  2022-01-27 20:28   test.xml
        0  2022-01-27 20:28   a/
       30  2022-01-27 20:28   a/test.xml
---------                     -------
       60                     3 files
```

When we run the following code, we can see, that it also outputs the directories.

```
def parse_xml(search_pattern) -> None:
    with ZipFile(DEFAULT_ZIP, "r") as my_zip:
        for file_name in my_zip.namelist():
            print(file_name)
```

Output:

```
test.xml
a/
a/test.xml
```

Fortunately, `zipfile` also provides a special `Path` class, which can be used to check whether the name is actually a file:

```
import zipfile

def parse_xml(search_pattern) -> None:
    with ZipFile(DEFAULT_ZIP, "r") as my_zip:
        for file_name in my_zip.namelist():
            if zipfile.Path(my_zip, file_name).is_file():
                print(file_name)
```

Output:

```
test.xml
a/test.xml
```